# DB2 SQL - Retrieve a Field's Max Value along with other fields

Tags: sql, db2

Maybe this may pose as a simple question, but well, I'm not able to figure out a solution

I have this prospective table:

Assume this data and Columns:

```
PERSONA   FECHA_PERF  SECUENCIA2  NIVEL4_RIESGO
---------+---------+---------+---------+-------
24226517  12.06.2018         53.  00           
24226517  12.06.2018         52.  04           
24226517  12.06.2018         51.  04           
24226517  12.06.2018         26.  04           
24226517  12.06.2018         15.  04           
24226517  12.06.2018         14.  04           
24226517  12.06.2018          7.  04           
24226517  08.05.2018         91.  04           
24226517  08.05.2018         90.  04           
24226517  08.05.2018         89.  03           
24226517  08.05.2018         78.  04           
24226517  08.05.2018         77.  04           
24226517  08.05.2018         69.  04           
24226517  08.05.2018         68.  04           
24226517  08.05.2018         67.  04           
24226517  08.05.2018         66.  04           
24226517  08.05.2018         65.  01           
24226517  08.05.2018         64.  04           
24226517  08.05.2018         63.  04           
24226517  08.05.2018         62.  04           
24226517  08.05.2018         61.  04           
24226517  08.05.2018         60.  04           
24226517  08.05.2018         52.  04           
24226517  08.05.2018         51.  04
```

FECHA_PERF is a date field, Secuencia2 is an integer field and Nivel4_riesgo is a Char(2) field and persona is a char (9) field

I need to obtain the latest NIVEL4_RIESGO value that has been inserted into the table for each **PERSONA** field, I need to take into account  both **FECHA_PERF** and **SECUENCIA2** fields

The table has many other fields, but for the sake of resutls, these are the fields needed

and the query's desired result should be:

```
--------------+---------
PERSONA  NIVEL4_RIESGO  
--------------+---------
24226517 00
```

Which corresponds to this record:

```
---------+---------+---------+---------+-------
PERSONA   FECHA_PERF  SECUENCIA2  NIVEL4_RIESGO
---------+---------+---------+---------+-------
24226517  12.06.2018         53.  00
```

Could you please provide a possible way oo implement this? I have, somehow, this sorted with subqueries, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it, specially when it comes to performance. I've considered using DB2 temporary tables for each subquery, but on this shop, well, they are a bit esoteric about it and are not that happy if I use them

```
SELECT A.PERSONA, A.NIVEL4_RIESGO                                    
FROM DIGEIN.GIPERF_PERS_GPP AS A                                     
  INNER JOIN                                                         
  (  SELECT PERSONA                                                  
           ,MAX(CHAR(VARCHAR_FORMAT(B.FECHA_PERF,'YYYY-MM-DD'),10) ||
                TRIM(TO_CHAR(B.SECUENCIA2,'00'))) AS VALORX          
           ,MAX(FECHA_PERF)                                          
           ,MAX(SECUENCIA2)                                          
     FROM DIGEIN.GIPERF_PERS_GPP AS B                                
     WHERE PERSONA = '24226517'                                      
       AND B.NIVEL4_RIESGO <> ''                                     
     GROUP BY  PERSONA                                               
  ) AS C                                                             
    ON A.PERSONA = C.PERSONA                                         
   AND CHAR(VARCHAR_FORMAT(A.FECHA_PERF,'YYYY-MM-DD'),10) ||         
       TRIM(TO_CHAR(A.SECUENCIA2,'00')) =                            
       C.VALORX
```

This query result is:

```
---------+---------+---
PERSONA   NIVEL4_RIESGO
---------+---------+---
24226517  00
```

Which is what i need.

Comment: Why is the current solution not satisfactory?

Comment: Is not that is not sattisfactory, I'm just wondering if there are other, maybe easier or better ways to do it, specially taking into account performance issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this would typically be done using `row_number()`:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by persona
                                order by fecha_perf desc, secuencia2 desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from DIGEIN.GIPERF_PERS_GPP p
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you only want the result for a single person, you can use the simpler:

```
select p.*
from DIGEIN.GIPERF_PERS_GPP p
where persona = XXX
order by fecha_perf desc, secuencia2 desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: Gordon, Thanks a lot for your input. I just looked at the manual, OLAP definition, ROW_NUMBER built in function, which i didn't knew, and actualyl works perfectly fine. First supplied query works brilliant. I was even using temporary tables and several queries, but this works perfectly. Thanks